# filtering based on price and city makes me curious

Tags: solr

I am using mongodb now and it is not good for filtering for sure, so I am thinking of using solr for this situation, the thing that makes me curious is, In a database, If I am willing to sort or filter values, I should add compound indexes to make filter better, In solr, I searched a lot, there is something called copyField, but I don't think that is not the answer for my question, so my question is, I should filter prices and cities and I should sort them by the price value, what should I add to my schema for this purpose or what should I do ?, I searched a lot and I cannot find anything, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define fields with appropriate field types (string, float) in the schema.xml

e.g. `<field name="cities" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`
e.g. `<field name="prices" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

You can mark them multivalued if multiple values for the fields.

You can then use [fq](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to filter the filter the results

e.g. `fq=(cities:Mumbai AND prices:100)`

You can also use range for the prices.

You can then use the [sort](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort) parameter `sort=prices desc`

Comment: thank you :) I am asking because, I did not get the logic of solr :) by doing this, is solr going to search all the documents ? or there is an efficient indexing system that solr uses, so solr will filter efficiently ?

Comment: this will not search the documents but will just filter the documents and this is highly performant as well .